# JavaScript Async function in class and method

Tags: javascript, class, asynchronous, methods

I am creating a map which displays bikes stations. My code was working but now I would like to create a class and it does not work anymore. Seems there is a problem calling the method with the async function. Can someone help me?

Thanks.

CLASS

```
class Map {

    constructor(targetElt, targetInfos, targetReservation, link) {
        this.targetElt = document.getElementById(targetElt);
        this.targetInfos = targetInfos;
        this.targetReservation = document.getElementById(targetReservation);
        this.link = link;
    }

    async infoStations(url) {
        let apiInfos = await fetch(url)
            .then(response => {
                if(response.ok) {
                    return response.json()
                }else{
                    console.log('Erreur URL');
                }
            })
            .then(result => {
                let stationInfos = [];
                for(let station of result) {
                    let point = {
                        name: station.name,
                        address: station.address,
                        position: {lat: station.position.lat, lng: station.position.lng},
                        status: station.status,
                        totalStands: station.bike_stands,
                        availableStands: station.available_bike_stands,
                        availableBikes: station.available_bikes
                    };
                    stationInfos.push(point);
                }
                return stationInfos;
            });
            return apiInfos;
    }
    initMap() {
        this.infoStations(this.link)
        .then(markerInfos => {
            let map = new google.maps.Map(this.targetElt, {
                center: {lat: -27.469434, lng: 153.024689},
                zoom: 14
            });
            for(let markerInfo = 0 ; markerInfo < markerInfos.length ; markerInfo++) {
                let myStation = new Station(this.targetInfos, markerInfos[markerInfo].name, markerInfos[markerInfo].address, markerInfos[markerInfo].status, markerInfos[markerInfo].totalStands, markerInfos[markerInfo].availableStands, markerInfos[markerInfo].availableBikes);
                let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: {lat: markerInfos[markerInfo].position.lat, lng: markerInfos[markerInfo].position.lng},
                    map: map,
                    title: markerInfos[markerInfo].name,
                    station: myStation
                });
                marker.addListener('click', () => {
                    this.targetReservation.style.display = "block"; 
                    marker.station.showStation();
                });
            }
        }); 
    }
}
```

SCRIPT

```
let myMap = new Map("bike-booking__map", "bike-booking__data__info-station", "bike-booking__data", "https://api.jcdecaux.com/vls/v1/stations?contract=Brisbane&apiKey=e4e72c38a3d668f8fb765f8ccc3c4913bfce501f");
myMap.initMap();
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you need to `await` on your `infoStations` method. At the moment you fire it off and the `initMap` method ends before the `infoStations` method is resolved. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @RobotEyes Thank you, I understand! But can you tell me how to await on my infoStations method, it is not clear for me. Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error or does nothing happen? You seem to be using two Promise paradigms async/await and promise chains

Comment: Also I wouldn't use `Map` as a class name. This is already a type of global object in javascript! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: The problem is solved. It was because my class was named Map. After your comment, I changed... and it worked. I never imagined it could be the problem, thank you :)

Comment: But I still have this error in the console : 127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) 
Vc
message: "initMap is not a function"
name: "InvalidValueError"
stack: "Error↵    at new Vc
__proto__: Error